# How can we resolve the sales order filter with sku gaves "Something went wrong with processing....." in Mageto 2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, admin, grid

The Sales Order Grid Not Working And It's Gives this kind of error when search by sku

> "Something went wrong with processing the default view and we have
> restored the filter to its original state."

[image]

in exception.log file i found this king of error.

> [2022-02-11 06:08:55] main.CRITICAL: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not
> found: 1054 Unknown column 'sku' in 'where clause', query was: SELECT
> COUNT(*) FROM `sales_order_grid` AS `main_table` WHERE (`sku` LIKE
> '%GGM6001%') {"exception":"[object] (Zend_Db_Statement_Exception(code:
> 42): SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'sku' in
> 'where clause', query was: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `sales_order_grid` AS
> `main_table` WHERE (`sku` LIKE '%GGM6001%') at
> /mnt/data/home/489837.cloudwaysapps.com/wxvjjsqbbs/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php:110,
> PDOException(code: 42S22): SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054
> Unknown column 'sku' in 'where clause' at
> /mnt/data/home/489837.cloudwaysapps.com/wxvjjsqbbs/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php:91)"}

Comment: Try to check logs in var/log directory (exception.log or system.log). Maybe some orders have missing values for some columns?

Comment: ok let me check

Comment: i found this kind of error in exception.log file , i add error in qustion